# Derivative of $f(x) = y^4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$(x^3 \cdot y^4)' = ?$

$a = x^3$ , $b = y^4$

$$(x^3 \cdot y^4)'= a'\cdot b + a\cdot b' = 3x^2 \cdot y^4 + x^3 \cdot (b')$$

Not sure what the derivative of $y^4$ would be, $(4y^3)$? Since the derivative of $(x\cdot y) = 1\cdot y + x \cdot y'$ and the derivative of $y' = y'$ instead of following the power rule.

Comment: from where do you get $$x^3y^4$$?

Comment: That's the question I am solving but I don't know how to solve the derivative of $y^4$ which is needed to solve the derivative of $(x^3\cdot y^4)$

Comment: @lakada what is $y$. Is $y$ a function of $x$? If it is, what is this function? You are trying to find the derivative with respect to x, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the product and chain rule we get $$(x^3y(x)^4)'=3x^2\cdot y(x)^4+x^3\cdot 4y(x)^3\cdot y'(x)$$

Comment: Why does $y^4 = y(x)^4?$

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a function of $x$, then $y(x)^4$ is a composite function and you need to apply the chain rule.

Comment: Derivative of $y(x)^4 = 4y(x)^3 \cdot (y+x\cdot y')?$

Comment: No, where do you get the extra factor $x$? $(y(x)^4)'=4y(x)^3·y'(x)$.

Comment: I took the derivative of $y\cdot x$ instead of $y(x)$ by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be a more specific in your question.
Are $x,y$ independent or $y = f(x) $ ? And towards which variable are you taking the derivative ?
If $y = f(x)$ then you probably want the answer of @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.
If not, then it is probably an exercise concerning partial derivatives.